# Why is the matrix positive semidefinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is SPD, $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ is the full rank matrix ($r<n$). The matrix $P$ is defined as
$P = AZE^{-1}Z^TA$ with $E=Z^TAZ$ (obviously $E \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ is also symmetric). The author claims that $P$ is positive semidefinite, but I did not get how it is? Can somebody show me how $P$ is a positive semidefinite matrix?

Comment: What does "SPD" mean? Are all matrices square matrices or what are their dimensions?

Comment: @ Alejandro Nasif Salum : $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, Z is a full rank rectangular matrix $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$ with $r<n$, and $E \in  \mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$

Comment: $P=AZE^{-1}Z^TA=AZ(Z^TAZ)^{-1}A=AZZ^{-1}A^{-1}(Z^T)^{-1}Z^TA=AA^{-1}(Z^T)^{-1}Z^TA=AA^{-1}A=A$. So if $A$ is SDP the same is true for $P=A$.

Comment: @ user126154: $Z$ is a rectangular matrix you cannot take its inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, argue that $E$ is positive-definite. This is because for any non-zero vector $v$, 
$$v^TEv = (Zv)^T A (Zv) > 0$$
since $A$ is SPD and $Zv \neq 0$ since $Z$ has full rank.

Next, argue that $P$ is semidefinite, by the exact same reasoning: for any vector $v$,
$$v^TPv = (Z^TAv)^T E^{-1} (Z^TAv) \geq 0$$
 since the inverse $E^{-1}$ of a positive-definite matrix $E$ is positive-definite.

Comment: @ user7530: Thanks for a nice answer. But then is P also not SPD, since $E^{-1} is also SPD$?

Comment: @EngDR No because $Z^TA$ is not full rank, so for some non-zero $v$ you will have $v^TPv=0$.